# 404 error with Ngrok while following Local Development with Google Sheets

Tags: python, xlwings, ngrok

I'm new to xlwings and i wanted to automate and display graph for a Google Sheet using a local Python.
But i can't connect the server with Ngrok (error 404).

I followed the xlwings doc, part Local Development with Google Sheets : [https://docs.xlwings.org/en/latest/pro/server/server.html#local-development-with-google-sheets-or-excel-via-office-scripts](https://stackoverflow.com).

First, in the **Part I: Backend** i don't understand what is the *"app.py"*, the file is not generated by the command.

Anyway my real problem is here. I run the server locally on 8000. And do the same with ngrok.
After copying the content to *"app scripts*" in Google sheet and run it, i've got an error 404 POST in my bash.

I also get the same error in Ngrok terminal.

Concerning the code, i'm just using the main.py from the doc :

```py
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, status
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
from fastapi.responses import PlainTextResponse

import xlwings as xw

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/hello")
def hello(data: dict = Body):
    # Instantiate a Book object with the deserialized request body
    with xw.Book(json=data) as book:
        # Use xlwings as usual
        sheet = book.sheets[0]
        cell = sheet["A1"]
        if cell.value == "Hello xlwings!":
            cell.value = "Bye xlwings!"
        else:
            cell.value = "Hello xlwings!"

        # Pass the following back as the response
        return book.json()


@app.exception_handler(Exception)
async def exception_handler(request, exception):
    # This handles all exceptions, so you may want to make this more restrictive
    return PlainTextResponse(
        str(exception), status_code=status.HTTP_500_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
    )


# Office Scripts and custom functions in Excel on the web require CORS
cors_app = CORSMiddleware(
    app=app,
    allow_origins="*",
    allow_methods=["POST"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
    allow_credentials=True,
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run("main:cors_app", host="127.0.0.1", port=8000, reload=True)
```

The only difference i see is my link with ngrok. The documentation refer to a "ngrok.io". And when i'm using `Ngrok http 8000` i got :

```
https://xxx-xxx.....xxxx.ngrok-free.app
```

Thank you and merry Christmas :)

Comment: PM from ngrok here. I'm not sure about the 404 error, but the link ending in a different domain shouldn't be an issue. We [updated our domains](https://ngrok.com/blog-post/new-ngrok-domains) earlier this year.